# How to exclude the topmost selection from Application.Selection.Areas?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to exclude the topmost selection from a list of selection(CTRL + Click) in a  column. For example, if I selected Cell V12 + V10 + V14 + V9. The topmost selection is V9. I have this code that loops through all the selected cells but I need to exclude the topmost selection (i.e V9).

Here's the working code:

```
Dim rngPart as Range
For Each rngPart in Application.Selection.Areas
    MsgBox rngPart.Address
Next
```

I need help with excluding the topmost selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break this up into a few functions to compose it together.

First I would want a function to find the top range based on its row. To do this we just need a simple loop and assign the range if it is less than the previous cell.

```
Private Function getTopRange(ByRef source As Range) As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In source

        If getTopRange Is Nothing Then
            Set getTopRange = cell
        End If

        If cell.Row < getTopRange.Row Then
            Set getTopRange = cell
        End If

    Next cell
End Function
```

Then I would create the function that would return the range excluding the top one.

Again to do that, we just need a simple loop. If it isn't the top cell, then union it to our return range value.

```
Private Function excludeTopRange(ByRef source As Range) As Range
    Dim topRange As Range
    Set topRange = getTopRange(source)

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In source

        ' Only add if not the top cell
        If cell.Address <> topRange.Address Then
            If excludeTopRange Is Nothing Then
                Set excludeTopRange = cell
            Else
                Set excludeTopRange = Union(excludeTopRange, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Function
```

Putting it all together you just call our new function!

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim source As Range
    Set source = Application.Selection

    Dim excluded As Range
    Set excluded = excludeTopRange(source)

    MsgBox excluded.Address

End Sub
```

It's a good [design](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#design) to try and keep your functions small and reusable like this. It's easier to read, debug, test, and reuse!